# JavascriptExecutor XPath with apostrophe

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver, apostrophe

I'm trying to find a text element using XPath using JavascriptExecutor. The problem is that the text has an apostrophe, and I don't know how to escape it in this case. Normally it is just enough with `\"`. Could you help me?

I have already tried the following options:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var path = '//*[text()=\"d'arrivée\"]/following-sibling::div/div';
var x = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;x.style.display='block';");`
```

and

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var path = '//*[text()=\"d\"arrivée\"]/following-sibling::div/div';
var x = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;x.style.display='block';");`
```

Comment: As @Andersson suggested, I had to put \\' to escape the apostrophe inside the text:

`code` ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var path = '//*[text()=\"d \\'arrivée\"]/following-sibling::div/div';
var x = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).ssingleNodeValue;x.style.display='block';");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below expression with escaped apostrophe:

```
'//*[text()="d\'arrivee"]/following-sibling::div/div'
```

When using a string between single quotes, you should escape an apostrophe with a single backslash. Double quotes don't need to be escaped in this type of string.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. I have to escape first the delimiters of the text in some way: text()=\"exampletext\", and then escape the apostrophe in text.

`code` ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var path = '//*[text()=\"d\'arrivée\"]/following-sibling::div/div';var x = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;x.style.display='block';");
`code`
P.S.I shortened the searched text in the question, and left a space ..., I have edited now the question.

Comment: Can you try `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var path = '//*[text()=\"d\\'arrivee\"]/following-sibling::div/div';
var x = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;x.style.display='block';");`

Answer (score 1):

First construct the XPath expression you need. In XPath 1.0 the only way to write a literal apostrophe is to use double-quotes as the string delimiter, so the XPath expression is:

```
//*[text()="d'arrivee"]/following-sibling::div/div
```

(although using "." rather than "text()" is better practice).

Then think about how to escape this as a string literal in your chosen host language, which in this case is Javascript. In Javascript, you can use either `'` or `"` as the string delimiter, and you must then escape any occurrences of the string delimiter with a backslash. So it becomes either

```
"//*[text()=\"d'arrivee\"]/following-sibling::div/div"
```

or

```
'//*[text()="d\'arrivee"]/following-sibling::div/div'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variant try to find another Xpath-locator without apostrophe. Do not use function "text()" or use part of text through with "contains()". I think it is real.

Comment: Using "contains()" searching only a part of the text works, but there are similar texts, and I would prefer an exact match. Thanks.